# JSON De-serialization Issue Illegal Value for primitive

Tags: apex, json

I'm running a REST API which is returning the below:

```
"id" : "fdgsdgsdsdgsdg",
   "pageevents" : [ {
       "name" : "test",
       "number" : "0123442",
       "homepage" : "www.test.com"
    } ],
    "goals" : [ {
       "name" : "test",
       "number" : "0123442",
       "homepage" : "www.test.com"
    } ]
} ]
```

Im using the below code to de-serialize it, so i can display it as a pageblocktable on a visualforce page however im getting the error :

> System.JSONException: Illegal value for primitive

```
public List<maMoments> getMomentsActivity() {
    Id contactId;
    if (contactId == null) {
        contactId = '0030O00001sqXJr';
    }

    String contactIdString = String.valueOf(contactId);
    String jsonResponse = this.AutomationDetailsMoments(contactIdString);
    system.debug(jsonResponse);
    List<maMoments> mAutomation = (List<maMoments>) JSON.deserialize(jsonResponse, List<maMoments>.class);
    system.debug(mAutomation);
    for(maMoments emailStructure : mAutomation){

    }
     return mAutomation;
}

public string AutomationDetailsMoments(String contactId) {
    contactId = '0030O00001sqXJr';
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/mickjdavies/Example/1.0.0/interestingmoments');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(contactId);

    // Send the request, and return a response
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    system.debug(res.getBody());
    return res.getBody();
}

private class maMoments {
    public String contactId;
    public String id;
    public List<String> goals;
    public String name;
    public String homepage;
    public String phone;
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm). `Json.deserialize()` only accepts apex types. You should try with `JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString)`.

Comment: You can't really use the strict deserialization approach because `number` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that is causing the immediate error is that goals is not a valid `List<String>` as it is a json object in your case. You also have a potential issue *if* you need to access the number property as number is a reserved keyword.

Two things to resolve:

1. Adding a class for goals will resolve your immediate issue.
2. Replacing number with number_Z in the JSON string to deserialize Properly, if you need the number property to be available

**Without needing the number property**

```
public with sharing class mytestClass {
    public static String tmp = '[{"id" : "0011400001Z4xuEAAR", "pageevents" : [ { "name" : "test", "number" : "0123442", "homepage" : "www.test.com" } ], "goals" : [ { "name" : "test", "number" : "0123442", "homepage" : "www.test.com" } ] } ]';

    public static maMoments[] doIt() {
        return (maMoments[]) json.deserialize(tmp, List<maMoments>.class);
    }

    public class maMoments {
        public String contactId;
        public String id;
        public List<goals> goals;
        public String name;
        public String homepage;
        public String phone;
    }

    public class goals{
        public string name;
        public string homepage;
    }

}
```

> 14:14:00.50 (89310700)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|(maMoments:[contactId=null, goals=(goals:[homepage=www.test.com, name=test]), homepage=null, id=0011400001Z4xuEAAR, name=null, phone=null])

**If you need the number property**

Replacing should be ok when you only have one reserved keyword.

```
public with sharing class mytestClass {

    public static String tmp = '[{"id" : "0011400001Z4xuEAAR", "pageevents" : [ { "name" : "test", "number" : "0123442", "homepage" : "www.test.com" } ], "goals" : [ { "name" : "test", "number" : "0123442", "homepage" : "www.test.com" } ] } ]';

    public static maMoments[] doIt() {
        return (maMoments[]) json.deserialize(tmp.replace('"number"','"number_Z"'), List<maMoments>.class);
    }

    public class maMoments {
        public String contactId;
        public String id;
        public List<goals> goals;
        public String name;
        public String homepage;
        public String phone;
    }

    public class goals{
        public string name;
        public string homepage;
        public string number_Z;
    }

}
```

> 14:17:09.44 (62331981)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|(maMoments:[contactId=null, goals=(goals:[homepage=www.test.com, name=test, number_Z=0123442]), homepage=null, id=0011400001Z4xuEAAR, name=null, phone=null])

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, didn't realise i needed to create a separate class for the object, got this displaying correctly now thank you